# Record "old" not assigned yet

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_update 
AFTER INSERT
ON "delivery" FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE premium1();
```

With this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION premium1() 
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
IF (TG_OP='INSERT') THEN
IF(select sum(amount) from delivery where cli_num=OLD.cli_num group by cli_num) > 500.00 THEN
    UPDATE client SET Type ='Gold' WHERE cli_num=OLD.cli_num;
END IF;
END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When inserting a new value in table delivery I'm getting the below error:

> ERROR: record "old" is not assigned yet Stan SQL:55000

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION premium1() 
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
IF (TG_OP='INSERT') THEN
IF(select sum(amount) from delivery where cli_num=NEW.cli_num group by cli_num) > 500.00 THEN
    UPDATE client SET Type ='Gold' WHERE cli_num=NEW.cli_num;
END IF;
END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 3):

In `INSERT` triggers `OLD` is not accessible/visible since the record wasn't yet in the database so there's nothing to compare it to. You have to change it to `NEW`.

From the [fine manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/trigger-definition.html)

> For a row-level trigger, the input data also includes the NEW row for
>   INSERT and UPDATE triggers, and/or the OLD row for UPDATE and DELETE
>   triggers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Kamil

Comment: @Kamil Gosciminski, it's not because AFTER but because of INSERT. Re-read quote you wrote in your answer and edit it, please

Comment: @Roman thanks, I didn't write what I meant at that time. Corrected!